# The set of homogeneous solutions of a clopen contains an hyperarithmetical set

Tags: co.combinatorics, computability-theory, ramsey-theory

In the context of Galvin-Prikry generalization of Ramsey's theorem, I read in a couple of papers ([1],[2]) that Solovay [3] proved that if $P$ is a clopen of $[\mathbb{N}]^{\mathbb{N}}$ then the set of homogeneous solutions for $P$ (i.e. the set of infinite sets $A$ s.t. either $[A]^\mathbb{N}\subset P$ or $[A]^\mathbb{N}\cap P = \emptyset$) always contains a hyperarithmetical set (this is what Clote calls a *basis theorem*).

I don't see this results being stated explicitly in Solovay's paper, so I guess it follows as a corollary of some other result. Could you please help me in identifying the theorem(s) in [3] from which the "basis theorem" follows?

---

[1] *Simpson, Stephen G.*, [**Sets which do not have subsets of every higher degree**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2271956), J. Symb. Log. 43, 135-138 (1978). [ZBL0402.03040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0402.03040).

[2] *Clote, Peter*, [**A recursion theoretic analysis of the clopen Ramsey theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2274171), J. Symb. Log. 49, 376-400 (1984). [ZBL0574.03030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0574.03030).

[3] *Solovay, Robert M.*, [**Hyperarithmetically encodable sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1997849), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 239, 99-122 (1978). [ZBL0411.03039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0411.03039).

Comment: Am I missing something, or is it Theorem 1.8 in [3] you are looking for?

Comment: Maybe...but if there is a solution that lands in $W$ and another one that avoids it I don't see how we could use the theorem 1.8 of [3] to conclude anything on how complicated these solutions are.